# Need help for making differential equations of following excercise

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis

I've trouble to find correct set of equations to solve in Maple.[image]

My set of equations with all resistors and caps identical:

1. \$  0 = \frac{V_i}{R} + V_x \times s \times C + \frac{V_0}{R} \$
2. \$  0 = \frac{V_x}{R} \$
3. \$  0 = V_o \times s \times C + \frac{V_o}{R} \$

I presume that the second equation is mistaken, can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is actually in the 3rd equation, which I believe should be:

\$ \Large  0 = V_o \times s \times C + \frac{V_o}{R_3} + \frac{V_o}{R_2} \$

or

\$ \Large 0 = V_o \times s \times C + 2 \times \frac{V_o}{R} \$ (if all Rs are the same)